# Is it possible to use x11vnc in proprietary software?

Tags: derivative-works

Are there any problems with using X11Vnc in my proprietary software stack? I am very new to this licensing stuff.

Comment: What license does it have? What does that license say?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, IANAL/IANYL.  According to [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11vnc), x11vnc is released under the GNU GPL, so unless you can get the agreement of the author(s), you may not make a non-free product derived therefrom.  You would probably be able to include x11vnc as a standalone part of a commercially-released product provided that (a) your product interacts with the x11vnc components solely through userspace (restrictions include, but are not limited to, a prohibition on linking your non-free code to x11vnc's libraries) and (b) you honour the GPL's obligations regarding source code with respect to x11vnc as you ship it.